# how to enable connect direct DMZ

Tags: ibm-datapower, dmz, connect-direct

We have an application that does sftp to external customers. Currently this goes through IBM Datapower that acts as a DMZ proxy that actually lookups the actual destination/user id password for the sftp which is used in the sftp of the files. the datapower box sits on the DMZ. Now we are replacing the sftp with IBM connect direct. Datapower doesnt seem to have a FSH for connect direct. any thoughts on how to get this working with datapower?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible I am afraid as DataPower doesn't support ConnectDirect. The only option is a TCP proxy object in Datapower but that doesn't offer any security at all, it's a port opening straight in.

The best option is to add a RFE here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=changeRequestLanding&BRAND_ID=181&PROD_ID=694&x=22&y=18

I know it has been up for discussion before and they have implemented the "Sterling Multi-Enterprise Integration Gateway Server" into the MPGW component so maybe that can be extended to also support ConnectDirect...

As of Chris3k's answer there is a way of tunneling it:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7X_7.0.4/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/cd_bridge_overview.htm

You still need the Connect:Direct Node though (and of course IBM MQ 7+ with FTE/MFT option)...

Answer (score 0):

If you have/use MQFTE v7.4+, then you can use it to perform connect:direct operation via DataPower.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7X_7.0.4/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/cd_bridge_overview.htm